# Populate nested dictionary with spreadsheet data

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have an idea of what I want my list of Python dictionaries to look like but am having issues pulling the spreadsheet data into the data structure.  The problem I have is that one row may have data to populate the parent dictionary values as well as 1 child.  For subsequent rows, if the values in the columns for the parent, are empty, then assume that the columns for the children belong to the previous parent.  If we come upon a new row where the parent data is not empty, consider it a new parent to add to the list.

This is an example of what the spreadsheet would look like:

```
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| name         | descr             | adminSt | authSt   | server_hostname_ip | server_descr | server_preferred | server_EPG  | server_minPol | server_maxPoll |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| test1-NTPPOL | Test NTP Policy   | enabled | disabled | 10.10.10.10        | NTP1 server  | yes              | oob-default | 4             | 6              |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|              |                   |         |          | 10.10.10.11        | NTP2 server  | no               | oob-default | 4             | 6              |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|              |                   |         |          | 10.10.10.12        | NTP3 server  | no               | oob-default | 4             | 6              |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| test2-NTPPOL | Test 2 NTP policy | enabled | disabled | 20.10.10.10        | NTP1 server  | yes              | oob-default | 4             | 6              |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|              |                   |         |          | 20.10.10.11        | NTP2 server  | no               | oob-default | 4             | 6              |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|              |                   |         |          | 20.10.10.12        | NTP3 server  | no               | oob-default | 4             | 6              |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
```

I would like the data structure to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "NTP_Policy1",
    "descr": "NTP Policy 1",
    "adminSt": "enabled",
    "authSt": "disabled",
    "servers": [
      {
        "hostname": "10.10.10.10",
        "descr": "NTP1 Server",
        "preferred": true,
        "server_EPG": "oob-default",
        "minPoll": 4,
        "maxPoll": 6
      },
      {
        "hostname": "20.10.10.10",
        "descr": "NTP2 Server",
        "preferred": false,
        "server_EPG": "oob-default",
        "minPoll": 4,
        "maxPoll": 6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "NTP_Policy2",
    "descr": "NTP Policy 2",
    "adminSt": "enabled",
    "authSt": "disabled",
    "servers": [
      {
        "hostname": "30.10.10.10",
        "descr": "NTP3 Server",
        "preferred": true,
        "server_EPG": "oob-default",
        "minPoll": 4,
        "maxPoll": 6
      },
      {
        "hostname": "40.10.10.10",
        "descr": "NTP4 Server",
        "preferred": false,
        "server_EPG": "oob-default",
        "minPoll": 4,
        "maxPoll": 6
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The closest code I came looked like this, however subsequent rows had the children appended to the parent level.

```
>>> import pyexcel
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> def excel_to_dict(sheet):
...     rows = sheet.iter_rows()
...     keys = next(rows)
...     dict_list = []
...     # For each row in the spreadsheet,
...     # Create an iterator pair so that the key is iterated over at the same time as its matching cell in the row
...     # Then save that pairing as descriptors of the switch
...     for row in rows:
...         dict = {}
...         dict['servers'] = []
...         server_atts = {}
...         for key,cell in zip(keys, row):
...             if str(cell.value) != 'None' and str(key.value) == 'name':
...                 dict[str(key.value)] = str(cell.value)
...                 parentKey = str(key.value)
...             elif (str(cell.value) != 'None' and str(key.value) == 'descr') or (str(cell.value) != 'None' and str(key.value) == 'adminSt') or (str(cell.value) != 'None' and str(key.value) == 'authSt'):
...                 dict[str(key.value)] = str(cell.value)
...             elif str(cell.value) == 'None':
...                 continue
...             else:
...                 server_atts[str(key.value)] = str(cell.value)
...         dict['servers'].append(server_atts.copy())
...         dict_list.append(dict.copy())
...     return dict_list
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('aci_config.xlsx')
>>> ntpPolsSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('ntp_pol')
>>> ntpPols = excel_to_dict(ntpPolsSheet)
>>>
>>> pprint(ntpPols)
[{'adminSt': 'enabled',
  'authSt': 'disabled',
  'descr': 'Test NTP Policy',
  'name': 'test1-NTPPOL',
  'servers': [{'server_EPG': 'oob-default',
               'server_descr': 'NTP1 server',
               'server_hostname_ip': '10.10.10.10',
               'server_maxPoll': '6',
               'server_minPol': '4',
               'server_preferred': 'yes'}]},
 {'servers': [{'server_EPG': 'oob-default',
               'server_descr': 'NTP2 server',
               'server_hostname_ip': '10.10.10.11',
               'server_maxPoll': '6',
               'server_minPol': '4',
               'server_preferred': 'no'}]},
 {'servers': [{'server_EPG': 'oob-default',
               'server_descr': 'NTP3 server',
               'server_hostname_ip': '10.10.10.12',
               'server_maxPoll': '6',
               'server_minPol': '4',
               'server_preferred': 'no'}]},
 {'adminSt': 'enabled',
  'authSt': 'disabled',
  'descr': 'Test 2 NTP policy',
  'name': 'test2-NTPPOL',
  'servers': [{'server_EPG': 'oob-default',
               'server_descr': 'NTP1 server',
               'server_hostname_ip': '20.10.10.10',
               'server_maxPoll': '6',
               'server_minPol': '4',
               'server_preferred': 'yes'}]},
 {'servers': [{'server_EPG': 'oob-default',
               'server_descr': 'NTP2 server',
               'server_hostname_ip': '20.10.10.11',
               'server_maxPoll': '6',
               'server_minPol': '4',
               'server_preferred': 'no'}]},
 {'servers': [{'server_EPG': 'oob-default',
               'server_descr': 'NTP3 server',
               'server_hostname_ip': '20.10.10.12',
               'server_maxPoll': '6',
               'server_minPol': '4',
               'server_preferred': 'no'}]}]
```

What does the code need to look like to populate the dict list correctly?  Is there a better spreadsheet format that may make it easier to import the data in?  I am trying to do this all in a single sheet, not multiple sheets.

Comment: can you not use `pandas` for this purpose? it will achieve same result with few lines of code.

Comment: you should convert it to `json`

Comment: what is the problem that you're encountering? is the data coming in but not as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest saving the .xlsx file in csv format since it is must easier to deal with. It will look something like this in text form:

```
name,descr,adminSt,authSt,server_hostname_ip,server_descr,server_preferred,server_EPG,server_minPoll,
test1-NTPPOL,Test NTP Policy,enabled,disabled,10.10.10.10,NTP1 server,yes,oob-default,4,6
,,,,10.10.10.11,NTP2 server,no,oob-default,4,6
,,,,10.10.10.12,NTP3 server,no,oob-default,4,6
test2-NTPPOL,Test 2 NTP policy,enabled,disabled,20.10.10.10,NTP1 server,yes,oob-default,4,6
,,,,20.10.10.11,NTP2 server,no,oob-default,4,6
,,,,20.10.10.12,NTP3 server,no,oob-default,4,6
```

Then you can use pandas to read the csv and convert it to json. Pandas has an `.iloc` function which allows you to first index by row and then by the column name.

```
import pandas as pd
from beeprint import pp

def excel_to_dict(sheet):
    dict_list = []
    last_test_dict = None
    for i in xrange(len(sheet)):
        # When we find a new row with a name value, we want to insert
        # the old test_dict into the dict_list and make a new test_dict.
        # Also, we want to skip the first row to not append an empty dict.
        if pd.notnull(sheet.iloc[i]['name']):
            if i != 0:
                dict_list.append(test_dict)
            test_dict = {}
            test_dict['name'] = sheet.iloc[i]['name']
            test_dict['descr'] = sheet.iloc[i]['descr']
            test_dict['adminSt'] = sheet.iloc[i]['adminSt']
            test_dict['authSt'] = sheet.iloc[i]['authSt']
            test_dict['servers'] = []
            server_info = {}
            server_info['server_hostname'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_hostname_ip']
            server_info['server_descr'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_descr']
            server_info['server_preferred'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_preferred']
            server_info['server_EPG'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_EPG']
            server_info['minPoll'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_minPoll']
            server_info['maxPoll'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_maxPoll']
            test_dict['servers'].append(server_info)
            last_test_dict = test_dict # keep a handle to our new dict
        else:
            # Use the handle to the last test dict created to add info
            # about a new server without modifying the name of the test
            server_info = {}
            server_info['server_hostname'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_hostname_ip']
            server_info['server_descr'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_descr']
            server_info['server_preferred'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_preferred']
            server_info['server_EPG'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_EPG']
            server_info['minPoll'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_minPoll']
            server_info['maxPoll'] = sheet.iloc[i]['server_maxPoll']
            last_test_dict['servers'].append(server_info)

    # In case we didn't enter the last test dict into the list
    dict_list.append(last_test_dict)
    return dict_list

sheet = pd.read_csv('sheet.csv', sep=',')
pp(excel_to_dict(sheet))
```

Comment: This appears to work perfectly.  The only question I have is the 'if i != 0: then dict_list.append(test_dict)'.  This would appear to mean as long as we are not on the first row and not on a row with a blank name, then append the test_dict to our main dict list.  Aren't we appending whatever was in test_dict the last time we went through this part of the code?  After this we grab the data from the line as expected.  I just don't understand why you need to append test_dict if we are not on index 0 and on a new name entry.

Comment: Right so the point of having that at the beginning is so that whenever we process a new row that _does_ contain a new test name we append the previous `test_dict` into the `dict_list`. However, when we come upon row 1, the previous `test_dict` would be empty and we would be trying to push an empty dict into the `dict_list`. So I make sure not to do that on i == 0. This also means that the final `test_dict` will not get entered into the `dict_list` inside the for loop so I added the line before the return statement.

Comment: I understand now.  Is there any way to generalize this function?  I have other sheets with different columns that will benefit from this function except it is hard coded to secific layout and I would need to code differently for every sheet.  Would constructing the data structure from the last column to the first be the easiest way of doing this?  I ask because i have a sheet with these headers: site, building, floor, room, row, rack.  A site has a name can have multiple buildings, a building has a name and multiple floors and so-on.

Comment: Essentially all the hard coded values are just names of columns in the two files. You could create two lists of the names of columns in both files and then split them up into sub lists for which columns you want to put into each dictionary. Then you can write loops to iterate through the correct lists and populate your dictionaries?